# Can "so" be used instead of "this" and mean the same thing in "this far" here?

Tags: synonyms

Can **so** replace **this** in the sentence below and mean the same thing?

This is a situation that a friend of mine and I were in a car going somewhere talking so much that we forgot how much we drove and went farther than the destination.

> I didn't know we came **this far**.

Comment: It could, or it couldn't, depending on the intended meaning.  **this** can imply a considerable degree (**so**) but the degree need not be considerable.  In your scenario in the car, they are synonymous.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you for the comment as always. But, what if the speaker had gone just a little tiny bit farther than the destination and there was no regard that the degree is considerable?

Comment: A "tiny bit farther than the destination" is to have overshot the destination. It is "considerable". Are you trying to say "just a tiny bit too far"?  *I knew we had passed our exit on the highway, and I thought it was 50 miles behind us. I didn't realize we had come **only this far**. The exit is only 2 miles behind us. Phew!*.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo And in that example you gave above, isn't **so** possible to replace **this**?

Comment: In my last example, **only this far** cannot be replaced with **so**. **only this far** can be paraphrased *not **that** far*.  I didn't realize we had gone only this far.  I didn't realize we had gone not that far.  **so** is deictic.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you very much. From your answers, I think **this** describes the current degree of something, and, on the other hand, **so** can be used the same way **only when the degree is considerable**. May I ask you if I am right with this sum-up?

Answer (score -2):

> I didn't know we came **this far**!

is an exclamation and entirely correct for making a statement.

You would use *so far* when asking a question:

> How far have we come **so far**?

In conclusion, you **cannot** replace *so* with *this* in this context.

Comment: I don't think I agree.  **So** is perfect acceptable in statements as well as questions.

Comment: -1 This is patently untrue. You could switch "so" and "this" in these sentences and they'd be perfectly correct